# Why is this month old answer showing up in my reputation tab

Tags: bug

I was just looking at my reputation tab and saw that a month old answer was on the top of the list, but the reputation I received for it is more than a month old. Back then it already showed on the top of the list and slowly moved down. The "reputation bar graph" shows correctly that my latest gotten reputation is 5 from a question.

Here's an image showing what I'm talking about.[image]

I tried a hard refresh, but it still shows. Is this a bug, or is there a different reason for this to happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31914091/timeline) for [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914091/missing-minutes-in-strtotime-timestamp), we can see that the user unaccepted and then reaccepted your answer today (after accepting then unaccepting another user's answer).

[image]